# how to step through lambda expression

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, lambda, visual-studio-debugging

I have this little method

```
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough]
    public static void Log(Database db)
    { 
        db.Log = s => MyLogger.Log(s);
    }
```

but the debugger still stop for every `s => MyLogger.Log(s)`

is there a way to tell the debugger to ignore this specific line?

king of boring to have to manually step to/over/out of it for each query

this `db.Log` thing is the entity framework 6 log

Comment: @gleng, i can also only press my ctrl-shift-f8, step over, which will do what you just said without having one more breakpoint. i want to be able to skip that.

Comment: "step over" instead of "step into"?

Comment: @MarvinSmit, I want it to be done by visual studio automatically, if there is a way to do it. I know i can do it like this. when you are debugging non-stop and you keep hitting the same F key, you don't want to juggle between 2 F key in case you do a mistake and have to go over again

Comment: set a break point past that line and hit F5?

Comment: Would "System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepperBoundary" do? (not tested myself)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this does what i want;

```
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough]
    public static void Log(Database db)
    {
        Action<string> Log = MyLogger.Log;
        db.Log = Log;
    }
```